# opentk / C# keyboard state

Tags: c#, keyboard, opentk

Using [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/), I'm having issues with the Keyboard State.  I'm trying to use Keyboard.GetState() but it fails.

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is a single 'click'.  Because the state-check is in UpdateFrames, the checks are milliseconds apart, meaning a single keypress will trigger the event multiple times.

I dont want to use KeyRepeat.False because I still want keys like W, S, A, and D to update per frame.  I just want some of the keys to be single-checked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now I switched to XNA to handle input, as I dont think th OpenTK input is fully developed yet.  much easier on that side, just set up a KeyboardState and test the state of the last from with the current one.  if they aren't the same, the button was just pushed.